# How to escape & in re:replace in erlang

Tags: html, url, replace, erlang

I have below Url, in that || I want replace back to & using re:replace.

"a href=\"http://znetratest23.com/wp-content/plugins/email-management/emailClick.php?userName=mar26reseller||reportType=C||campaignId=4F4F52CEA941153719000000||email={{toemail}}||score=40||url="

Like this...

```
"a href=\"http://znetratest23.com/wp-content/plugins/email-management/emailClick.php?userName=mar26reseller&reportType=C&campaignId=4F4F52CEA941153719000000&email={{toemail}}&score=40&url="
```

I have tried with below code but it doesn't work for me.

```
EscClickUrl = "a href=\"http://znetratest23.com/wp-content/plugins/email-management/emailClick.php?userName=mar26reseller||reportType=C||campaignId=4F4F52CEA941153719000000||email={{toemail}}||score=40||url=",
EscClickUrl1 = re:replace(EscClickUrl, "||", "\&", [global, {return,list}]).
```

Can anyone help me on this...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use double backslashes:

```
1> EscClickUrl = "a href=\"http://znetratest23.com/wp-content/plugins/email-management/emailClick.php?userName=mar26reseller||reportType=C||campaignId=4F4F52CEA941153719000000||email={{toemail}}||score=40||url=",
1> re:replace(EscClickUrl, "\\|\\|", "\\&", [global, {return,list}]).
"a href=\"http://znetratest23.com/wp-content/plugins/email-management/emailClick.php?userName=mar26reseller&reportType=C&campaignId=4F4F52CEA941153719000000&email={{toemail}}&score=40&url="
```

Comment: Hey bro thanks it is working for me now...but actual issue is something different I am giving temporary soln. see I have a html content and and I have to replace all href value to my href value. so I am replacing by StrTemplateContent = re:replace(StrTemplateContent0, "a href=\"", EscClickUrl, [global, {return,list}]), but in this wherever & is there it is replacing with href...how to escape that & shud not get replaced in my url. thanks!

Comment: Could you give short example of what you want?